# How to make mock JdbcTemplate.queryForObject() method

Tags: junit, mockito

I am new for Junit and Mockito and i am not understand how to write test case for below JdbcTemplate and i tried but getting exception ,Can some one help me please

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
```

### Code

```
@Repository
public class BaaisnEvcIdMSRepository {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Transactional
    public RowMapperServerResponse getQueryEvcidRepository(BaaisnEvcIdRequest baaisnEvcIdRequest) {
        RowMapperServerResponse rowMapperServerResponse =  jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
            "select * from Master_Circuit WHERE master_ckt_id =  ( select max(master_ckt_id)  from master_circuit  WHERE product = ? AND id_type = ?)",
            new Object[]{baaisnEvcIdRequest.getProduct_type(),baaisnEvcIdRequest.getLata()}, new BaaisnRowMapper());
        return rowMapperServerResponse;
    }
}
```

### test class

```
public class BaaisnEvcIdMSRepositoryTest {

    @InjectMocks
    BaaisnEvcIdMSRepository baaisnEvcIdMSRepository;

    @Mock
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void getQueryEvcidRepositoryTest() {


          when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(eq(ArgumentMatchers.anyString()), refEq(new Object[]{ArgumentMatchers.anyInt()}), eq(String.class))).thenReturn("data");

          verify(jdbcTemplate, times(1)).queryForObject(eq(ArgumentMatchers.anyString()), refEq(new Object[]{ArgumentMatchers.anyInt()}), eq(String.class));

    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you start with looking up the examples on junit and mockito with `MockitoJUnitRunner`? Attempt the code and then post the problems you are having rather than asking for direct solution.

Comment: Yogesh i edited my code please check

Comment: How is `BaaisnRowMapper` related to `eq(String.class)`? Also you are missing the call to your method under test.

Comment: Please guide me with cose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InvalidUseOfMatchersException` is coming from your use of `eq(ArgumentMatchers.anyString())` and `refEq(new Object[]{ArgumentMatchers.anyInt()})`. You are not supposed to wrap `ArgumentMatchers` inside anything else.

You also seem to aim at the wrong `queryForObject` method. It should be this [`one`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-int:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-) instead.

As mentioned before you need to call the `method under test` before doing the verification.

```java
@Test
public void getQueryEvcidRepositoryTest() {

    // use a real `BaaisnEvcIdRequest` object if you can
    BaaisnEvcIdRequest req = Mockito.mock(BaaisnEvcIdRequest.class);
    Mockito.when(req.getProduct_type()).thenReturn(1);
    Mockito.when(req.getLata()).thenReturn(new Object());

    Object[] array = new Object[]{req.getProduct_type(),req.getLata()};

    Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.eq(array), Mockito.any(RowMapper.class)))
           .thenReturn("data");

    baaisnEvcIdMSRepository.getQueryEvcidRepository(req);

    Mockito.verify(jdbcTemplate, Mockito.times(1))
           .queryForObject(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.eq(array), Mockito.any(RowMapper.class));
}
```